# How to display due date across multiple timezones in an Angular application?

Tags: angular

We have an ASP.NET Core web api that stores UTC **Due Dates** in SQL Server in a `DATETIME2` column. So the fifteenth day of August 2020 looks like `'8/15/2020 12:00:00 AM'` on the server. Our Angular client uses `{{dueDate | date : 'shortDate'}}` and displays `8/14/2020` in EDT at 1:09 PM. How do we get it to display and format the proper date so that clients in all time zones see `8/15/2020`? Is it even a good idea to show the same date across time zones?

On the network, `dueDate` is a part of a JSON message that looks like this:

```
[{"dueDate":"2020-08-15T00:00:00-04:00"},{},{}]
```

Our metadata knows it is a date and converts it to a Javascript date so it can be formatted for the current culture.

I realize this is the correct date in EDT when it is midnight UTC, but a user may not. Since this is a due date for a bill, we would rather not show the user what looks like an earlier date than it actually is.

Comment: Can you share the contents of "dueDate"? Sounds like you should simply treat it as a string since you do not want different displays in different time zones.

Comment: Done. We need to treat it as a date so Angular can format it for the current culture.

Answer (score 1):

If you treat what comes back from the server as a string only, you can create a new date object in the client with what you get from the server but only pull out the year, month and day from the string.  If you just pass the full string from the server to the Date constructor, it's going to convert it to the user's timezone.

`new Date(2020, 8, 15)` will create August 15, 2020 at 12am in the user's current timzeone and should display properly with Angular's date pipe.

Things will get messy if you send it back to the server though, as the server might try to convert it.

Comment: My question is partially technical and partially practical in that I'm not certain whether we should show the same date in all time zones. Is it common practice to ignore the time part and force dates to be the same across timezones?

Comment: It really depends on the use case.  Dealing with dates/times/timezones just sucks in general...  In my opinion, I would try and treat it (and store it) as a string in this case.  In the future someone may try to use that date column in a different way, and not realize other parts of the app are just using the date portion and stripping out the time/timezone. This way, its clear, this is not a date time and should not be used as such